# Formula to increment value of sheet no and not the cell number in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a formula say as below
=Req_113!B3
This means ,take value of B3 from Sheet "Req_113". This formula i want to apply to a column. the value is always fixed from B3 but i just want to vary the sheet name like Req_114,Req_115,Req_116....

The formula should be expanded to each cell as like this

```
=Req_114!B3
=Req_115!B3
=Req_116!B3
.
.
```

I tried to drag the formula to apply all cells below but the cell number got varied and not the sheet name.

Please suggest the right method to apply the formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `=Req_114!B3` is in row 1 you can instead use

```
=INDIRECT("Req_" & (113 + ROW()) & "!B3")
```

Comment: Thank you...fyi Some sheets are yet to be created ....It is showing this error when applying the formula ......"Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'Req_121!B3'. It is not a valid cell/range reference".

Comment: Well, has Req_121 been created already? If you just don't want the error you can wrap it inside `IFERROR(<formulaabove>, "")`

Comment: Req_121 not created yet.. I have created till 120..the formula is tried as like this                                                                                                           =IFERROR((INDIRECT("Req_" & (113 + ROW()) & "!B3"), ""))                            this is not working...no value is coming..just blank

Comment: Thats what the if error wrapping is supposed to do. What do you want it to show if it doesn't exist yet?

Comment: =INDIRECT("Req_" & (109+ ROW())& "!B3",TRUE)..Thank you it worked this way..you were right somehow the row() funtion returned the number of rows ahead and it did not quite matched with the value i expected..now worked..